# Minimizing multivariate quartic function with L4-norm

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I need to minimize a function $v(h)$ of the form

\begin{align}
v(h) = \langle  g,h \rangle + \langle Ah, h \rangle + a \cdot \|h\|_4^4,
\end{align}

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is scalar, $g,h \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are vectors, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is a quadratic and symmetric matrix, but not necessarily positive semidefinite, $ \|h\|_4^4 = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i^4 $ is the sum of entries taken to the fourth power element-wise.

The problem is the L4-norm in the last term.

If I want to write down the first derivative in vectorial form, I need to use the Hadamard product to get
\begin{align}
\nabla v(h) = g + 2Ah + 4a \cdot h \odot h \odot h,
\end{align}

but I don't see a way to make use of this expression.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form solution?

Comment: Ideally yes, but it might already be enough to get an approximate solution to $ h^* = \arg \min_h v(h)$.